# Identical mount points for two file systems when installing Linux

Tags: partition, system-installation, crunchbang

So, I'm going through Crunchbang's installer (very similar to Debian's), and am at the partitioning step. I chose the 'Guided - use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM' method (usually I do manual without encryption). It wiped my disk, and I set my encryption pass phrase. So now this is my current partition configuration

```
LVM VG $HOSTNAME,    LV root - 242.7 GB Linux device-mapper (line
     #1           242.7 GB     f  ext4      /
LVM VG $HOSTNAME,    LV swap_1 - 7.1 GB Linux device-mapper (line
     #1             7.1 GB     f  swap      swap
Encrypted volume (sda5_crypt) - 249.8 GB Linux device-mapper (cry
     #1           249.8 GB     K  lvm
SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) - 250.1 GB ATA WDC WD2500BEKT-7
     #1  primary  254.8 MB  B  F  ext2      /boot
     #5  logical  249.8 GB      f  crypto    (sda5_crypt)
SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sdb) - 16.0 GB JetFlash Transcend 16GB
    #1  primary    16.0 GB  B     fat32
```

The last entry is obviously the USB drive I've booted from, but I'm including it for completeness. I may have inadvertently done something to it.

When I try to write changes to disk, I get the following error message

```
                     [!!] Partition disks

          Identical mount points for two file systems
Two file systems are assigned the same mount point (/): LVM VG
$HOSTNAME, LV root and SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #5 (sda).

Please correct this by changing mount points.
```

Comment: This looks like an installer bug, where the installer is misunderstanding what `sda5` is used at. I've never encountered that bug with the Debian installer, but maybe Crunchbang got an installer version that happens to have such a bug.

Comment: That appears to be the case. It works fine with the Live-CD graphical installer of the same version (and ISO).

Answer (score 2):

Burning the ISO to a DVD and installing with that instead solved this (I used ImgBurn).